# ubuntu can't Mount the other partition of my drive

Tags: mount

I have Ubuntu 16.04 alongside Windows 10.i have a partition of personal files.why does Ubuntu says "unable to mount .....maybe Windows was hibernated or has auto fast-booting "
Please i need help.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 has fast startup enabled by default. This saves the RAM to the disk. Ubuntu will not mount the Windows partition when it is in this state because it could cause Windows to err when booting.

To disable fast startup, go to Control Panel > Hardware and sound > Change what the Power Buttons Do (under Power Options) and click `Change settings that are currently unavailable`, uncheck Fast Startup, and reboot to Ubuntu.

## This will notably slow your Windows boot time, as Windows will boot from a cold start every time.

Comment: thank you very much Moose. i come back to u soon to report what has come as result.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I fixed mine.

open terminal and enter this command

```
sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdXY
```

replace the XY according to your partiton.. Ex..sdb1

You can find this in the message which comes when try to open the partition

Hit enter key

Enter your password when prompted.